# "arguments" property in Chrome has functionality changed?

Tags: javascript

Here is my case:

```
function x(a) {
    console.log(a + '=' + arguments[1]);
}
x('arg0', 'arg1');
```

In Firefox 4 and not so long ago in Chrome, this was the content of 'arguments':

```
arguments[0] = 'arg0';
arguments[1] = 'arg1';
```

In Chrome, now only the named arguments are in the `arguments` array. So it's only 1 long, instead of 2.

So my questions:

1. When and how did this change?
2. How can I make this work again?

Comment: It works for me as expected, Chrome 13.x (arguments array contains both arguments).  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function x(a) {
    console.log(a + '=' + arguments[1]);
}
x('arg0', 'arg1');
```

Result:

```
arg0=arg1
```

It works just fine on Chrome, you just have to name the function, otherwise it's not callable.

Comment: Yes, made a mistake in my code sample. The above works indeed in the console. Will update my sample cause there really seems to be a problem with this.